# What is the "default revision"?

Tags: 8, workflows

I'm using the Workflow module in Drupal 8 and I saw this checkbox on the "add a state" screen (/admin/config/workflow/workflows/manage/help/add_state):

> **Default revision** When content reaches this state it should be made the default revision; this is implied for published states.

What exactly is meant here by "default revision"?  Why is it implied for published states?

Comment: Just FYI, as I understand it, some of the terminology and concepts for revisions aren't completely stable yet, see eg. [#2940575](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2940575), [#2942907](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2942907), [#2875154](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2875154), [#1643354](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1643354).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So that means it will become the active revision shown to users. So if a revision is published its got to become the default revision as it will be shown as the page content for normal users

When you select "Archived" for a piece of content you'd want that to become the default revision too so that when users look at the page they'd see access denied. But you wouldn't have the published option ticked for "Archived"

And draft you wouldnt want to become the default revision because it's not supposed to be shown to users in that state